Training endgames with "royal non-king" pieces
For endgame training with kids, I often let them chase a knight with a queen until "mate". (The poor is thought to be royal.) The same could be done for almost any material constellation, e.g. you may try a two-rook steamroller on the poor knight. On CSE, I may not list 10 different questions (for the most relevant materials), so I ask differently: Are there tablebase or other resources giving the "correct" outcome of several of these endgames? (The weaker side probably should have a knight, since the king is handled already in the "normal" endgame mating techniques, a pawn is toast except against N, and any long ranger usually can only be caught with 5 queens or so. 3Q vs B might be interesting.)
